# Generate pages from XML based on ID's using PHP/XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am building a small website that uses a catalog.xml for a list of objects. I also have menu.xml and footer.xml files.

I want to generate a separate page for each object from catalog.xml based on the object ID from page URL.

I was able to party achieve it using this code:

```
<?php
$goods = simplexml_load_file('catalog/catalog.xml');
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
foreach($goods as $id => $item) {
if(!($item->attributes()->id == $_GET['id'])) {
  continue;
}

$xslt = new xsltProcessor;

$xsl = new domDocument;
$xsl->load('item.xsl');
$xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$xml = new domDocument;
$xml->loadXML($item->asXML());

print $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
exit;
}
} else {
$xslt = new xsltProcessor;

$xsl = new domDocument;
$xsl->load('item.xsl');
$xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$xml = new domDocument;
$xml->loadXML($items->asXML());

print $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
}
```

Example of catalog XML:

```
<goods>
    <item type="shampoo" id="0001">
    <title>Object name</title>
    <brand>Dodo</brand>
    <weight>226,6</weight>
    <country>Germany</country>
    <price>34</price>
    <description/> 
    <thumb>image.jpg</thumb>
    <photo></photo>
    </item>
</goods>
```

The only problem is that menu.xml and footer.xml are not icluded here.

I have item.xml file that I'd like to use for generating the object page:

```
<page>
    <head><header href="head.xml"/></head>
    <content><catalog href="catalog/catalog.xml"/></content>
    <foot><footer href="footer.xml"/></foot>
</page>
```

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

As item.xsl is processing the item record, it could also reference item.xml via the document() function.

I will illustrate a simple approach that only attempts to pull the header and footer name out of item.xml.  You could add more complex logic to process each node of item.xml.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <page>
    <head>
      <xsl:variable name="head" select="document('item.xml')/page/head/header/@href"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($head)/*"/>

      <!--process the actual input content sent to the stylesheet-->
      <content><xsl:apply-templates select="*"></content>

      <xsl:variable name="foot" select="document('item.xml')/page/foot/footer/@href"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($foot)/*"/>
    </head>
  </page>
</xsl:template>
```

More complex approach: If you actually needed to process the item.xml file with a stylesheet, you could do something like the following.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('item.xml')/*">
  <xsl:with-param name="catalog-item" select="."/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this has partly worked for me. But since I am using a custom xsl framework it seems to conflict with this setup. Will dig further. I am wondering if there is a better way to select nodes from catalog.xml based on ID passed in the URL.